# How to fix the data filter problem on onChange event in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that filters out the data onChange events. It working fine as far as the filtration goes, **But the issue is with the onChange event and setState**

I'm using React Select to give the value onChange:

```
<Select
  id="status"
  isClearable={false}
  options={statusOptions}
  defaultValue={statusOptions[0]}
  onChange={(choice) => handleStatusFilter(choice.value)}
/>
```

Here the statusOptions are :

```
const statusOptions = [
  { value: '', label: 'Clear' },
  { value: 'draft', label: 'Draft' },
  { value: 'ready', label: 'Ready' },
  { value: 'expired', label: 'Expired' },
]
```

Now onChange event I'm calling the `handleStatusFilter` :

```
// state
const [status, setStatus] = useState('')

// ** handleStatusFilter
// ** Function to handle status filter
const handleStatusFilter = (value) => {
  let updatedData = []
  const dataToFilter = () => {
    if (title.length || type.length || createdAt.length || createdBy.length || status.length) {
      return filteredData
    } else {
      return results
    }
  }

  setStatus(value)
  if (value.length) {
    updatedData = dataToFilter().filter((item) => {
      const startsWith = item.status.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())
      const includes = item.status.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())

      if (startsWith) {
        return startsWith
      } else if (!startsWith && includes) {
        return includes
      } else return null
    })
    setFilteredData([...updatedData])
    setStatus(value)
  }
}
```

So it works the first time when the user selects any option, but not on changing his selection after that. For example;
data gets filtered when the user selects the `draft` option. But when directly he goes from `draft` to `ready` it doesn't work, and if the user clears the state hitting the `Clear` option from `statusOptions`, and then the user selects `ready` then data gets filtered with this value properly.

I'm assuming there's should be a way to clear the value onChange instead of Clearing manually selecting the empty string.
So how to counter this problem, is there any better approach to follow, instead of the setState method.

Comment: So it does select the other value, but it does not filter as you like it to be filtered?

Comment: Yes, It filters out but not with the correct value but if I console the value onChange it gives the correct value but not the `filteredData` according to that value

Comment: btw. you are setting `setStatus(value)`value twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is more or less with this condition here:

```
  const dataToFilter = () => {
    if (title.length || type.length || createdAt.length || createdBy.length || status.length) {
      return filteredData
    } else {
      return results
    }
  }
```

Probably it returns `results` on the first selection because all values in the condition are falsy. For sure `status.length` is `0` and therefore `falsy`. From then on it allways returns `filteredData`, since `status.length` is truthy. Obviosly the filtered values do not include the other values anymore. So whatever you select, you will allways filter the filteredData again.

Instead you have to filter the original value `results` on each selection.

```
     updatedData = results.filter( // here use results instead of filtered values.
(item) => {
          const startsWith = item.status.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())
          const includes = item.status.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    
/** besides that, this can be simplified
          if (startsWith) {
            return startsWith
          } else if (!startsWith && includes) {
            return includes
          } else return null
        })**/
    return startsWith || includes
```

Edit1:
What I said above is not wrong, but it does not consider the other filters. So in general you are restricting your results so that they can not be filtered any further. Instead, you have to apply all the filters in the same filter function, to filter down the values. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-forked-izobsl?file=/src/App.js) is a codesandbox with a full example.

I used a useEffect for that and a simple html select for demonstration. But you can easiely apply that to your code.

Comment: I'm using dataToFilter() , cz there can be other filters like on the `type` and more and they all collectively return `filteredData` lets say I have selected status and then started filtering type with separate filter function, But in the end, all returning the filtered data, If clears the all the results get displayed.

Comment: ah, ok now I understand it better. But still the problem is the same, you have to apply the filters differently. Because now, even if you change from draft to ready, the filteredData is still the same. I will try to make a better example.

Comment: @FaisalNazik see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks for the effort, You are right this should work and I'll definitely be following this approach. will give feedback soon.